# Why does it so much time for Mac to identify and show external drive?

Tags: macos, mac, external-hard-drive, sd-card, window

In windows when I insert my external HD / SD card it shows it within few seconds.
In my Mac it sometimes takes a few minutes!

What would cause this delay?

Comment: I don't have this behavior in my MacBook. Did you test with other storage devices yet? There could be obscure compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this happen when there was subtle corruption in the storage device's data structures. Copy all of your files off of it and reformat it on your Mac.